# What is this type of Target when using AR

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, markers

[image]

I'd like to make this type of AR project. 
but I don't know how to make this.
Is these makers are images or 3dObjects? or something different type of markers?

I'll make program using Unity with Vuforia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These cannot be markers, as they are too small and no features to detect.

This is probably geo-based, and you cannot use Vuforia to do it because it does not support geo-location. You can try Wikitude, perhaps.